# How to create categories by custom lookup_field?(django-oscar-api)

Tags: python, django-oscar

project/mycustomapi/views/admin/product.py

```
from rest_framework.generics import CreateAPIView
from oscarapi.views.admin.product import CategoryAdminDetail

class MyCategoryAdminDetail(CategoryAdminDetail, CreateAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'uid'
```

urls.py

```
path("category/<uuid:uid>/",MyCategoryAdminDetail.as_view(),name="my_category_admin_detail"),
path("category/", CategoryAdminList.as_view(), name="my_admin_category_list"),
```

All requests work correctly, except for post, it always creates a new category at the root, no matter what uid I'm referring to.